# Android robotium testing

Tags: android, robotium

I am very beginning in robotium and i can configure and run a very simole application with robotium.I need a some complex application code for robotium test.Kindly provide any link for this

Answer (score 0):

You want us to provide you with a code you can use for Robotium?
Why not just take some of the [sdk API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) then? Those should be complex enough
else try [Zxing's Barcode scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) which is opensource-